# fixing things from a LiveBoot session

Tags: lightdm

I switched from LightDM to something else when I was messing with my system late at night.  When I rebooted, the screen went black.

I'm currently booted from Bhodi Linux on a flash drive, and am wondering how to access my Ubuntu 16.x installation and switch back to LighDM.

My apologies for the general cluelessness of this post.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to use Bhodi's file manager to see my mounted drive with Ubuntu installed.  /etc/xll shows that LightDM is my default DM, so now I don't know why my screen is black.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please don't use the answer space to add info to your question. Instead *edit* your question to include the new info. :)